# Click and Mousemove for iPhone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, iphone

I am having trouble with mouseover and click events. It works on the desktop/laptop web browsers but not on iPhone's Safari. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function tog(v){return v?'addClass':'removeClass';} 
$(document).on('input', '.clearable', function(){
$(this)[tog(this.value)]('x');
}).on('mousemove', '.x', function( e ){
$(this)[tog(this.offsetWidth-100 < e.clientX-this.getBoundingClientRect().left)]('onX');   
}).on('click', '.onX', function(){
$(this).removeClass('x onX').val('');
});
</script>
```

The X is the clear icon that appears in each search field but I just cant "click" it on the iPhone. Replacing 'mousemove' for touchmove didn't work. And I wasn't able to adapt any jQuery Mobile plug-in unfortunately, i am a noob coding. Thank you! Happy Hallo'

Answer (score 3):

u must use `touchstart` and `touchmove` for iphone

Comment: could you orientate me on that please?

Comment: u can use it simply:
... on('mousemove touchmove', '.x',function( e ){//do sth});  
and:
on('click touchstart',function( e ){//do sth});

Comment: Fot test write some simple script like this:
$('some selector').on('touchstart',function(){alert('touchstart')})

its work?

Comment: still no, so frustrating! you think you could adapt an answer with my code?

Answer (score 0):

As stated above the iphone browser safari has no mouse therefore you need to use the touchstart and touchmove events.

Check out this. Note firefox mobile and safari handle touch in a similar manner and the MDN docs are a bit more helpful than the w3c docs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Touch_events

And the W3c docs:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-touch-events-20131010/

Comment: thanks but i was looking for a more concrete adaptation to my model